# How to suppress JDBC SQLWarnings?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to convert a MySQL stored procedure to java code. It's pretty simple SQL. It creates three temporary tables and then does a select based on them. However, I'm having trouble with SQLWarnings related to Data Truncation being thrown while creating the last temp table.

I'm not looking for an explanation of the warnings themselves. I was getting the same warnings during execution of the stored procedure (due to improperly formatted datetime fields), only there it didn't cause me any problems. In the java version, after Statement.executeUpdate() throws an SQLWarning, the temp table I was attempting to create doesn't exist.

How can I suppress the SQLWarnings? I'd prefer to be able to log a message noting the warning text, but I want my temp table to successfully be created as well.

My code looks something like this:

```
sqlStatement = "create temporary table mytemptable as (select ...) ;";
try {
    stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
    // Throws SQLWarning about Data Truncation
} catch (SQLWarning sqlW) {
    logInfo("SQLWarning Caught: " + sqlW.getMessage());
}
stmt.executeQuery("select * from mytemptable "); 
// Throws SQLException because mytemptable doesn't exist
```

Comment: Tried this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqltest/2.0/en/writing-tests-warning-supp.html

Comment: Maybe bad wording on my part, but like I said in my post I don't want to pretend the warnings don't exist. I'd like to be able to get the warnings, but I don't want them to interrupt execution of my code by throwing an SQLException.

Comment: Ok, in this case the whole tmp table has not been created. So just ignore the warning will not help. Can you try: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytemptable AS SELECT * FROM {yourtable} WHERE 0=1;
ANd a second statement:
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytemptable SELECT * FROM {yourtable};

This again will not return the warning..... It will keep your code running

Comment: I saw the IGNORE syntax in a couple places but it looks like that will completely remove the warning though right? It looks like the create table statement also supports an IGNORE keyword before the select, but then I won't get the warning at all...

Why are warnings thrown as exceptions at all? According to this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html, "Warnings do not stop the execution of an application", but clearly if they are a subclass of SQLException, they do stop the execution of an application...

Comment: If the SQL does not work on command line, consider it an exception. In your case that seems to be it. So yes, strange it is categorized as a warning. Can you also catch an exception and see if anything shows up there?

Comment: If I run the same SQL from MySQL command line it works. It tells me there are a few warnings, and if I run 'show warnings;' I can retrieve them, but all temp tables are created and my select afterward works just fine.

Comment: Replacing the initial statement with "create temporary table mytemptable ignore select ...;" creates the temporary table and allows my application to run through, and then if I use Statement.getWarnings() I can retrieve the warnings.

Thanks! Do you maybe want to give your response as an answer so I can approve it? Otherwise I'll add it as the answer.

Comment: Can you see if there is no uncaught exception? (Just catch exception instead of warning, see if anything shows up).

Comment: That whole section of code was wrapped in a try {} catching SQLExceptions separately. No exceptions are thrown for sql warnings if I have "ignore" before the selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it's a little strange but the equivalent of this worked:
    create temporary table mytemptable ignore select ...;

This way, no exception is thrown by jdbc, but you can still call getWarnings() on the Statement object to get a list of warnings that were ignored.

Thanks Norbert van Nobelen for helping me figure this out in the comments of the OP.